# Increment value if provide date is date of array in Mongodb using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I want to decrement slotsAvailable by 1 and increment slotsBooked by 1 if provide courtId is equal to courtId which in slotTracker and provided date is there in dates array

### Sample Data

```
 {

"slotTracker" : [
    {
      "courtID" : 1,
      "dates" : [
        {
          "date": "2021-03-17T08:03:02.197Z",
          "slotsBooked": 0,
          "slotsAvailable": 10
        },
            
        {
          "date": "2021-04-17T08:03:02.197Z",
          "slotsBooked": 0,
          "slotsAvailable": 15
        },      
      ]
    },
    {
      "courtID" : 2,
      "dates" : [
        {
          "date": "2021-03-17T08:03:02.197Z",
          "slotsBooked": 0,
          "slotsAvailable": 15
        },
            
        {
          "date": "2021-04-17T08:03:02.197Z",
          "slotsBooked": 0,   //increase this by 1
          "slotsAvailable": 5   //decrease this by 1
        },      
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

for example: provided courtId is 1 and provided date is "2021-03-17T08:03:02.197Z". so it will change the slotAvailable couter

```
{
    "courtID" : 2,
     "dates":[{
          "date": "2021-04-17T08:03:02.197Z",
          "slotsBooked": 1,   //increase this by 1
          "slotsAvailable": 4   //decrease this by 1
      },
     {
          "date": "2021-03-17T08:03:02.197Z",
          "slotsBooked": 0,
          "slotsAvailable": 15
      },
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.sample.update({
    courtID: 2, 
    "dates.date" : "2021-04-17T08:03:02.197Z" 
   } , 
   {$inc : {
         "dates.$.slotsBooked" : 1, "dates.$.slotsAvailable" : -1} 
    });
```

Please try this out :)